# Dutch language exams, CNaVT certificates versus NT2 certificates

Tags: cefr, dutch

I am interested in comparing the **CNaVT's "Maatschappelijk Formeel (FORM) – B1"** certificate to the **Nt2's "Programme I"** certificate in terms of their difficulty. Moreover, I am interested in comparing the **CNaVT's "Zakelijk Professioneel (PROF) – B2"** certificate to the **Nt2's "Programme II"** certificate in terms of their difficulty. Generally speaking, is it easier to pass CNaVT exams or Nt2 exams at the same CEFR level?

CNaVT certificates are briefly described at [CNaVT.org](http://cnavt.org/), while NT2 certificates are described at [State Exams Dutch as a Second Language (Nt2)](https://www.staatsexamensnt2.nl/item/state-exams-dutch-as-a-second). However, the information that is available online is not enough to achieve my goal.